# Flot Area Chart

Tags: javascript, flot

Is it possible to make an area chart in flot? I've noticed that there is a "stack" plugin. The image below is the effect I want to create. There is only one problem, the stack plugin automatically **adds** the component data. I don't want that. I only want the fill in effect.[image: Image of stacked data]

I tried the fill between property, but that makes an annoying color blending (see below):

[image: blending colors]

In the stack example, the colors don't blend at all. That's the visual effect I'm going for.

**UPDATE**
The code I used to make it work was:

```
  var dataSet = [
        {id: "A", label: "Demand (kW)", color: "#2980B9", data: d, lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1, fill: .5}},
        {id: "B", label: "Demand (kW)", color: "#D35400", data: d2, lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1, fill: .5 }, fillBetween: "A"},
        {id: "C", label: "Demand (kW)", color: "#C0392B", data: d3, lines: { show: true, lineWidth: 1, fill: .5 }, fillBetween: "B"}
    ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can [set the fill color](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-data-series) for a line chart to produce an area chart.

Setting the fill color below for a line chart:

```
var placeholder = $("#placeholder");
var data = [];

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true, fill: true, fillColor: "rgba(86, 137, 191, 0.8)" },
        points: { show: true, fill: false }
    }
};

$.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

**EDIT:**
After looking at the result, here's how I got it to work. You need to include the Stack and FillBetween plugins (I had to do it in that order):

```
var placeholder = $("#placeholder");

var data = [
   {data: data1, id: "Data1ID"},
   {data: data2, id: "Data2ID", fillBetween: "Data1ID"},
   {data: data3, id: "Data3ID", fillBetween: "Data2ID"}
]

var options = {
    series: {
        lines: { show: true, fill: true },
        points: { show: true, fill: false }
    }
};

$.plot(placeholder, data, options);
```

Comment: Please see the update above. This kind of works, but the colors don't match up the way I want them to.

Comment: @DiodeDan [This question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flot-graphs/JcxMpTp-HHs) in the [flot google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/flot-graphs) talks about how to get it working. You should be able to use the same plugin without stacking.

Comment: @DiodeDan After doing a little more digging, I think I've found a simpler way. I've edited my answer to show how I got it to work.